# mysql compare a vatchar column with date(now) giving wrong result.(I cannot alter the table.)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, datetime

I have a table with following attributes

```
id(int)  |  shift_id(int)  |  emp_id(int)  |  start_date(varchar)
```

The column startdate actually stores date in format - `"dd/MM/yyyy"` (from asp.net)

Now I have to perform a query in which i have to filter all result where startdate is greater that today

So i wrote the following query

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(start_date,'%d/%m/%Y'), DATE(NOW())
FROM   emp_shift_relation
WHERE
  STR_TO_DATE(start_date,'%m/%d/%Y') > DATE(NOW())
```

But I am getting wrong result.
Some values that I am getting are as follows

```
"id"    "shift_id"  "emp_id"    "start_date"    "STR_TO_DATE(start_date,'%d/%m/%Y')"    "DATE(NOW())"
"335"   "2"            "115"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"340"   "1"            "118"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"349"   "2"            "121"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"353"   "2"            "123"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"357"   "1"            "125"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"361"   "2"            "129"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"367"   "2"            "131"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
"371"   "1"            "132"    "06/04/2013"    "2013-04-06"    "2013-05-11"
```

As you can see the start_date is actually less that now. Please help me to correct the query. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Just a question, why not use a `DATE` to store the date in instead of a locale sensitive `VARCHAR`?

Comment: because table was created 2 years back and only the operation then was to show the date in uk format so it was easy for developer to define it as varchar. Now it has expanded and Changing will have to be reflected in many pages and services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date format is this:

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```

you need to use this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(start_date,'%d/%m/%Y') > DATE(NOW())
```

instead of:

```
STR_TO_DATE(start_date,'%m/%d/%Y') > DATE(NOW())
```